# Use printf() (@printf in Julia) to print an exponent having a base of '0.'

Tags: printf, julia

I am looking to output floating point numbers using `@printf` in Julia to display in a specific format, as follows:
0.56234680356E-09. This format is being produced by the Fortran code of `write(*,'(5E20.11)')`.  What I'm currently getting with `@printf("%19.11E")` is 5.62346803557E-10. Both of these numbers are floating point numbers (A `real` type in the [Fortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/KIND-Type-Parameters.html), and a `Float64` in [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Core.Float64)), so I don't believe there is an issue in that regard. When the type is changed to `Float32` in Julia, the floating point numbers are not identical.

Is there any way to specify having a 0 base number using printf or (@printf in Julia)?

Comment: I guess there is no package that does that since it is not that conventional.. But you can instead have the fortran output with `ES20.11` instead of `E20.11`, this will give you the scientific output as in Julia.